# iPhone encrypt and decrypt mp4 files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mp4

Can anyone suggest or provide a reference link of how to do the mp4 files encryption and decryption in iPhone/iPad ? I have tried google it but I couldn't fine any answers from it.

All I want is to encrypt the mp4 files and store into the apps bundle. And decrypt it before start playing the mp4 file. Since I don't want people to use some third party tools to steal the mp4 files.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It won't help prevent your mp4 from getting stolen.Since you have to play it ,then it's there in the temp dictionary.

Anyway if you still wish to do this, simply convert it into a NSData and save it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can decode them, you can encode them just in any ways...

Something as simple as the Caesar cipher will work... Or you can do more complicated stuff...
An MP4 file is just bits... So you can crypt/decrypt them as you want...