# How to protect personal documents in my app for the maximum

Tags: iphone, security, ipad, nsfilemanager

I want to protect the user's document downloaded via my app. 
- If I store the files in Document folder of iOS, iTunes will read them, right?
- If I store the files in Library or a subdirectory of it, files will be cleaned when the app is upgraded?
- The NSFileManager has a NSFileProtectionKey property. But I'm not sure what exactly it can do to protect the files? Does it can prevent other app from reading the user's files?

Overall, I want the files only can be read in my application, other than iTunes or other jailbreak app.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every app is in a SandBox. It means other apps can't access your app files, even from low-level functions.

So they are quite secure.

You can actually see this with this little app, available from the AppStore:

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/freeware/filesystem/

Apps are located in /var/mobile

Comment: Thanks Macmade. But how about if a person use a jailbreak app to browse the files? How can I encrypt a file, maybe a large file like a video? Can CCCryt encrypt a large file? How about the performence? Thanks again.

Comment: You may be interested in that subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182165/iphone-encrypt-and-decrypt-mp4-files